# Как сделать чтобы поток блокировался после вызова функции?

Tags: python

Есть две функции - `fun_1()` и `fun_2()`. 
Нужно запускать `fun_1` каждые **`10`** сек. Из нее вызывается функция `fun_2`.

После того как отработал поток `fun_1`, нужно запускать отдельно поток с функцией `fun_2`. 
`fun_2` должна вызываться например **`20`** раз.

Основная проблема, что мне нужно сделать так:

- запустить поток с `fun_1`.
- После запустить `fun_2`, прошло **`10`** сек, `fun_2` не успела отработать **`20`** раз, но уже время работать `fun_1`.
- Мне нужно приостановить второй поток с `fun_2`, запустить первый поток с `fun_1`, когда отработает `fun_1` возобновить поток с `fun_2`.

Я попыталась сделать через `lock` **`theared`**. Но получается так, что пока полностью не отработает поток **`20`** раз с функцией `fun_2`, поток с `fun_1` не запустится.

Пример кода

```
import threading
from threading import Lock
import time
lock = Lock()

def fun_1():
    i=0
    while True:
        print('fun1')
        fun_2()
        print('!!!!!')
        time.sleep(10)

def fun_2():
    global lock
    with lock:
        print('fun2')

if __name__=="__main__":
    
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=fun_1)
    t1.start()
    copy = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    for item in copy:

        t2 = threading.Thread(target=fun_2)
        t2.start()
```

Comment: GIL не дает использовать многопоточность в python так как это происходит в других языках. Т.е. в  python одновременно может выполняться только 1 thread. 
Описанное вами поведение можно достичь через async, ну или на крайний случай через multiprocessing.

Comment: @Tr1nks, могли бы вы объяснить или привести пример через async?

Comment: добавил пример с async

Answer (score 0):

Если добавить ожидание окончания `t2`, то можно обеспечить вклинивание исполнения `t1` в цикле для `t2`.
Иначе получается, что вы сразу наплодили кучу потоков `t2` (для всего списка), они всем скопом встали в очередь по `lock`, и `func_1` вызвав `func_2` после `sleep` встаёт только в конец этой очереди.

```
import threading
from threading import Lock
import time
lock = Lock()

def fun_1():
    i=10
    while i < 100:
        print('fun1', i)
        fun_2(i)
        i += 10
        print('!!!!!')
        time.sleep(5)

def fun_2(x):
    global lock
    with lock:
        print('fun2', x)
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__=="__main__":
    
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=fun_1)
    t1.start()
    for item in range(-1, -20, -1):

        t2 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: fun_2(item))
        t2.start()
        t2.join()
```

```
fun1 10
fun2 10
!!!!!
fun2 -1
fun2 -2
fun2 -3
fun1 20
fun2 20
!!!!!
fun2 -4
fun2 -5
fun2 -6
fun1 30
fun2 30
!!!!!
fun2 -7
fun2 -8
fun2 -9
fun1 40
fun2 40
!!!!!
fun2 -10
fun2 -11
fun2 -12
fun1 50
fun2 50
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Для работы в асинхронном режиме необходимо в задачах иметь место переключение контекста (в данном случае это [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep)).
Обычно подобные места это операции чтения/записи; ввода/вывода; ожидания ответа на вебсокете и проч., они бывают как синхронные так и асинхронные

```py
import asyncio


async def func1():
    while True:
        print(f'## func1 called')
        await func2('### func2 from func1')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


async def func2(title=None):
    print(f'{title or "func2"} called')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def async_main():
    asyncio.create_task(func1())
    for index in range(10):
        await func2()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(async_main())
```

Временные интервалы уменьшены вдвое для удобства.

```sh
func2 called
## func1 called
### func2 from func1 called
func2 called
func2 called
func2 called
func2 called
func2 called
## func1 called
### func2 from func1 called
func2 called
func2 called
func2 called
func2 called

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Если в задачах нет мест для переключения контекста (все синхронное) то можно использовать [`.run_in_executor(self, executor, func, *args)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) в который передать синхронные функции.

```py
import asyncio
import time


def func1():
    while True:
        print(f'## func1 called')
        func2('### func2 from func1')
        time.sleep(5)


def func2(title=None):
    print(f'{title or "func2"} called')
    time.sleep(1)


async def async_main():
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, func1)
    for index in range(10):
        await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, func2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(async_main())
```

```sh
## func1 called
### func2 from func1 called
func2 called
func2 called
func2 called
func2 called
func2 called
func2 called
## func1 called
### func2 from func1 called
func2 called
func2 called
func2 called
func2 called
...
```